# How to make JSON request?

Tags: iphone, json, nsmutableurlrequest

See the format below

```
    {
  "layer_id":"1Wn",
  "name":"Example Place",
  "latitude":"45.5037078163837",
  "longitude":"-122.622699737549",
  "span_longitude":"0.62",
  "extra":{
     "description":"Portland",
      "url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portland"
      }
    }
```

How can I make JSON request form such format

Comment: I think the old SO questions might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528834/send-json-request-with-restkit-rkparams

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456966/how-to-send-json-data-in-the-http-request-using-nsurlrequest

Comment: ya, i want to set from client side, and throught POST I will send to server,

Answer (score 0):

What about using a framework like [json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) to get all the JSON details right?

Have also a look at this [S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275883/generating-a-json-payload-for-post-http-request-in-objective-c) about a sample code.

Once you have got your JSON payload as a string, you can then send it to your server according  to its API.

Comment: but nested data, like extra, what about them?

Comment: How can I convert, it is nested

Comment: json-framework will take care of that. That is why I suggested of using a framework to do all the JSON processing. You will not have to worry about it.

Comment: storage.locationlabs.com/docs_create.html See this link, I want to do like this, alright?

Comment: see the link, I want like this, I want to make such request, that is in link that I shared, read it a bit please